# Is this getent hosts answer wrong

Tags: dns, cpanel, vps, nameservers

I have some DNS issues and I am trying to figure out if this is a correct I should get when I run this on VPS

```
getent hosts test.com
69.xx.xx.xxx    server.test.com server www.test.com www test.com test testuser
```

for other sites the answer looks like this

```
getent hosts justhost.com
74.220.195.132  justhost.com
```

Are the first result ok? where are the values taken from?

**Update:**
If it helps

nslookup test.com 127.0.0.1
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53
server can't find test.com: NXDOMAIN

---

dig @localhost test.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 56197
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;test.com.  IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 24 14:32:24 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41

---

Pinging the ns1 gives me the correct server ip 
Pinging the domain name gives me the old server ip
Is this usual?

Answer (score 0):

From an analysis on intoDNS (http://www.intodns.com/blackcatadvertising.com) it seems that the nameserver are not setted properly. Check both on your DNS provider (if it's not you) and on cPanel how they are setted. If you are sure that they are right as they are right now I would ask when did you created the domain? Sometime is required after the creation in order to let the DNS spread

Comment: @orbitory yeah, they seem to be setted wrongly. What are the current setting on the vps? Have you added an "a" record for them?

Comment: Yes they both have A entries, could it be the propagation time?

Comment: Depends on when you have added it (and if you have changed it).
And of course on how much the TTL has been set (usually the default value is 86400 (seconds) or 3600 (much better), but I use to lower amount when I have to debug the DNS settings)

Comment: I tried changing that as well in WHM. I saved the A records one more time but they looked fine before as well. Seems like nslookup blackcatadvertising.com 127.0.0.1 is not reporting that it can't find server. maybe the host did something. Pinging ns2 works as well but pinging the domain still doesn't work

Comment: Pinging the host will only work in the end, when the DNS has been properly set and you'll be able to see your website from the domain. Let's try to wait a bit (or somebody that has another idea about how to fix this)

Comment: The more I reload that page the more I get confused. The result isn't unique, it changes the more you reload the page... And checking with other websites, e.g. (http://dnschecker.org/#NS/blackcatadvertising.com), the result changes... No idea, hopefully it's a temporary thing
However I just noticed that the set TTL is 172800 (~2 days!), so by now we just have to wait (but, as I suggested you before, change the TTL to something smaller meanwhile you need to set the DNS)

Comment: Just got in touch with godaddy, they are trying a reconcile. Maybe their system was not properly transmitting the new records. The host says there is an non-resolution loop happening because we should have used IPs instead of name servers. Fingers crossed hopefully it will work soon

Comment: Any ideas if it's a vps/hosting problem or a registrar problem. They blame each other and I don't have a way to prove it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

fixed via [How to fix a dig command with status: REFUSED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734342/how-to-fix-a-dig-command-with-status-refused), basically I had to edit names.conf to have allow-query to any, and restart names