# How to fix a dig command with status: REFUSED?

Tags: dns, named, dig

I need help fixing a status refused. I had a look at the `named.conf` and everything looks ok.

I even changed `allow-query` to `any`, it used to be `localhost`.

```
dig xxx.com @ns1.xxx.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> xxx.com @ns1.xxx.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 41866
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxx.com.   IN  A

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: xx.xx.xx.xxx#53(xx.xx.xx.xxx)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 25 23:04:48 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To solve the issue I first installed bind9.
2. I edited my resolve.conf to show the below:

   ```
   #DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
   #FallbackDNS=
   #allow-recursion { any; };
   ```
3. Then I edited the line below in the bind9 config file

   ```
   # run resolvconf?
   RESOLVCONF=yes
   ```

Comment: Yes! needed to comment `allow-recursion { any; };`, for me under `options { ...` in the file `/etc/named.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I think I had to do a 
service named restart. Everything started working almost immediately

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same looking issue by changing `allowed-query` in bind's `options` configuration section. I included my vpn's network `10.1.0.0/24` to access dns:

```
options {
    ...
    allow-query { localhost; 10.1/24; };
    ...
};
```

After that I ofc executed `sudo service named reload` to reread the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a near-identical `REFUSED` line running Arch, and while my local machine had no problem with `dig` commands, my Arch server couldn't with bind already installed.

Edited and commented `allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; };` for this...

**/etc/named.conf** :

```
options {
...
#allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; };
...
}
```

Restarted bind with

```bash
systemctl restart named
```

Then `dig` works just fine.